# How do I correctly echo checkboxes in a PHP table?

Tags: php, css, checkbox

I have a table which is full with data from my database. I am now trying to implement a delete feature on that table, I do have the correct syntax to echo checkboxes but I don't know how to format the line correctly so the corresponding checkbox aligns correctly with each row. Any ideas? (I currently have the line echo'd above the closing table tag. Which makes the boxes appear above the table)

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $answer = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if ($answer->num_rows > 0) 
    {
 echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Stock</th><th>Delete Product</th></tr>";

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["product_id"]

     echo "0 results";
     }
```

Comment: This is a CSS issue. It would be good that you also post your markup and your styles.

Comment: Also, the input should be in a <td>.. or it will not validate..

Comment: <style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style> @Vucko this is the only CSS I'm using

Answer (score 2):

Insert the checkbox in an additional table cell (td). 
A `<tr>` element contains one or more `<th>` or `<td>` elements. Another content is not treated as part of that row.

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["product_id"]
 . "</td><td>" . $row["product_name"]
 . "</td><td> " . $row["product_description"]
 . "</td><td> " . $row["product_price"]
 . "</td><td> " . $row["product_cost_price"]
 . "</td><td> " . $row["product_stock"]
 . "</td><td>" . $row["product_ean"]
 . "</td><td>" .'<input name="delete['.$row['product_id'].']" type="checkbox">'
 . "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Thanks very much.. I'll mark as the correct answer.